# Default SSH user on Linux

Tags: ssh

What is the entry I should add to my `.bashrc` file so I can specify a default user for making SSH connections? For example, if I want it to be root and want to SSH to x, if I type `ssh x`, it should default to a connection of `ssh root@x`.

By default, Linux seems to default to whatever user you are logged in as. I.e., if I am logged in as "peter", typing `ssh x` will result in a connection of `ssh peter@x`.

Keep in mind I still want to override the default at times, so doing something like

```
alias ssh='ssh root@'
```

is not the most ideal solution.

Comment: I would even claim that aliasing *any* system command to itself with extra parameters is always a bad idea. You're going to have weird behavior in a year from now when you forget you've done this and spend two weeks pulling out your hair until you finally realize that you sabotaged yourself.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A better solution than putting an alias in your bashrc, would be to use a ssh config file

```
cat ~/.ssh/config

HOST *  
     USER root
```

You can also specify certain subdomains use certain users. Useful if your laptop travels between networks.

```
HOST 192.168.*.*
     USER homeuser

HOST 10.2.*.*
     USER workuser
```

You could even configure by domains, and use different ssh keys for different domains.

```
HOST *.microsoft.com
     USER bill
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/microsoft/id_rsa

HOST *.apple.com
     USER steve
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/apple/id_rsa
```

You can also add sections that apply to multiple hosts, e.g.

```
HOST rasbpi1 rasbpi2 rasbpi3
    USER pi
```

Read more about the format by executing `man ssh_config` or [here](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config)

Comment: Note that when `ssh` scans the config file it will use the first match it finds, so put the least specific matches at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 1):

## How to have a default user, and host-specific users

To be clear, if you want BOTH a **default** user AND host-specific users, you need to use `Host *`, and put it at the bottom of the config file:

`~/.ssh/config`:

```
#
# Aliases
#

Host dev
    Hostname dev.example.com

Host mac
    Hostname mac.local


#
# Host-specific users
#

Host dev dev.example.com
    User root

Host mac mac.local
    User me


#
# Default user
#

Host *
    User app
```

## References

- https://therootcompany.com/blog/ssh-defaults-config-and-priorities/

Answer (score 0):

You can do an alias to ssh using the -l option, so:

> alias ssh='ssh -l defaultuser'

The -l option gives the login user but what is interesting is that the user, if any, given before the host information overrides this. So if you start

> ssh host

After setting the alias above it will login as defaultuser, while if you start

> ssh newuser@host

Will anyway get newuser and not defaultuser from the "-l" option

This works at least on a few OpenSSH installations that come packed with standard Linux distros.

Comment: Using the ~/.ssh/config file is by far the preferred approach, as yours can have unintended side effects.